# How to Load Binary File Into Struct and get the data?

Tags: c#, struct, stream, binaryreader

I'm done searching any topic on stackoverflow to solving my problem, but i still can't solving my problem with my code
I want to reading binary file using c# , and make a struct for it

here is the code

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct YourStruct
    {            
        [FieldOffset(44)]
        public int none;  // 4 bytes
        [FieldOffset(48)]
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 156)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr, SizeConst = 156)]
        public String alldata;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFilePath = @"F:\dat\bintest.bin";

        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(strFilePath);

        YourStruct aStruct;
        //int count = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(YourStruct));
        int count = 791616;
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[count];
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        readBuffer = reader.ReadBytes(count);
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(readBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        aStruct = (YourStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(YourStruct));
        handle.Free();

        Console.WriteLine("None = {0}", aStruct.none);
        Console.WriteLine("Data : {0}", aStruct.alldata);
    }
```

The problem is , when i run this project, aStruct.alldata show nothing , like didn't read the file

Any solution for this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr, SizeConst = 156)]
```

To

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 156)]
```

Comment: I Already use it before commenting that , but the result seems same

Comment: But I can run the code with ByValTStr while I always get an access violation error with the LPStr. ByValTStr will load 156 bytes into your struct, that's for sure.